Is there a way to log a local folder as input to a run in MLflow?
I am new to MLflow, and I am wondering if there is a way to log a data folder locally stored on my system as "input data" to a training run. The dataset consists of images, which means the formats supported by mlflow.data such as Pandas dataframes, Numpy array or Tables do not apply.
My current solution for this is to include the data folder as a hyperparameter to the run, but it would be better to have a more formal way for logging the folder as input training data.
Thanks!

I'd be interested to know this as well. It seems there's no such feature at the moment. The closet thing I know is to use log_artifact to upload the contents of the folder, and then something like mlflow.note.content to log a tag which indicates the uri of the uploaded folder (https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html). This is similar to what log_input does, although it doesn't include a digest hash of the contents. Apart from that the feature probably needs to be requested in github to the mlflow team.

Try mlflow.log_artefacts if it doesn’t work you use dvc which will points to the same s3 server
